# CodeIgniter limit posts per page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I am creating a blog with [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter). My homepage shows posts that are coming from the database. I want to limit the posts for a page and create a link at the bottom to bring the next posts.
Please someone teach me how to do it with some example.

Thanks.

controller code

```
<?php
class Mysite extends CI_Controller
{
function index()
{
$this->load->model('posts_model');
$data['result']=$this->posts_model->getAll();
$this->load->helper('html');
$this->load->view("header");
$this->load->view("home",$data);
$this->load->view("footer");
}
?>
```

model code

```
<?php
class Posts_model extends CI_Model{
public function getAll(){
$this->load->database();
$query = $this->db->get('posts');
return $query->result();
}
}
```

?>

view code

```
<?php
foreach($result as $row) {
$a_url="mysite/single/".$row->id;
echo "<div id="."'postdiv'".">";
echo "<h1>".anchor($a_url,$row->title)."</h1>";
echo "<p>".$row->content."</p>";
echo "<p>Posted by : ".$row->author."</p>";
echo "<br>";
echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: try this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: take a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: post code, else use google. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice blog showing load more pagination using jquery and codeigniter.

http://www.thetutorialblog.com/php/twitter-like-pagination-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Sample code. Try yourself

```
function getcountryByname($limit=NULL, $start=NULL)  //select country
    {
        if($limit!=NULL) $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('country');
        $this->db->order_by("country_name", "ASC");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: can anyone tellme why I am not allowed to ask more questions on this site ?

Comment: Because of low quality of questions.

Comment: I was under the impression that i can ask anything here but nevermind.

Comment: First of all accept answers of your questions. May be you are under question ban http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans